# Windows Service Bus 1.1 configuration hangs

Tags: windows, servicebus

Trying to configure Windows Service Bus on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials.

Both the Wizard and power shell stops on "Generating certificate" and never gets any further. No errors.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

 Running New-SBFarm.
    Created and configured Service Bus gateway database.

VERBOSE: [03.01.2015 15:23:28]: Created and configured Service Bus farm
management database.
VERBOSE: [03.01.2015 15:23:38]: Created and configured Service Bus gateway
database.
VERBOSE: [03.01.2015 15:23:38]: Configuration added to farm management
database.
VERBOSE: [03.01.2015 15:23:38]: Generating Certificate.
```

The SbGatewayDatabase and SbManagementDB databases have been created. But that's all. Any ideas on how to proceed or get more details on what the problem is?

Comment: There are no errors in the event log as I can see. Note that this server is also hosting SQL server as well as the "active directory"  role being a "Essentials" server.

Comment: do you have RabbitMQ or any other AQMP enabled services running?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you. No matter what I tried I could not get the default to work, my services kept hanging at certificate generation. Here are my steps that finally worked.

1. Exit the hanging configuration wizard.
2. Use SelfSSL to generate your own certificate
3. Use SQL Management Studio to delete out the recent failed install
4. Enter the Service Bus Config wizard again and do a custom install
5. Remove check for "automatically generate certificate" and then select yours from the list.

Use other settings as planned as you had planned before.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it work by doing the following:
1. Choose advanced and not default installation
2. Choose an already existing certificate
3. Use a "normal" domain user and not the domain admin that I tried as service bus manager